# onclick for radio button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write this program for this survey I want a user to answer, after they have completed the survey they would go to click on submit and it would display confirmation of their choices. I can't get this to work for the life of me.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Satisfaction Survey </title>
<script Language ="Javascript">
  function testpage() {  
    errmsg = " ";
    confirmmsg = " ";
    errflag = false; 

    if ( document.form1.rdservice[0].checked == true ) {
      confirmmsg = confirmmsg + "<br> Overall is very satsified" ;
    }

    if ( document.form1.rdservice[1].checked == true ) {
      confirmmsg = confirmmsg + "<br> Overall is satisfied" ;
    }

    if ( document.form1.rdservice[2].checked == true ) {
      confirmmsg = confirmmsg + "<br> Overall is neutral" ;
    }

    if ( document.form1.rdservice[3].checked == true ) {
      confirmmsg = confirmmsg + "<br> Overall is unsatsified" ;
    }

    if ( document.form1.rdservice[4].checked == true ) {
      confirmmsg = confirmmsg + "<br> Overall is very unsatsified" ;
    }

    if ( (doucment.form1.rdservice[0].checked == false) &&        
         (doucment.form1.rdservice[1].checked == false) && 
         (doucment.form1.rdservice[2].checked == false) && 
         (doucment.form1.rdservice[3].checked == "false") && 
         (doucment.form1.rdservice[4].checked == false)) {
      errflag = true;
      errmsg  = errmsg + "<br> You forgot to select an option";
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form  name=form1  method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Please take a few moments to complete this satisfaction survey.  </legend>   
    <fieldset>  
    <legend> Overall, how satisfied were you with the product / service? </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="rdservice" value="v"> Very Satisfied
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rdservice" value="s"> Satisfied
    <br>        
    <input type="radio" name="rdservice" value="n"> Neutral
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rdservice" value="un"> Unsatisfied
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rdservice" value="vu"> Very   Unsatisfied
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="subm1" value="Submit"  onclick="testpge()">
    <input type="Reset"  name="Res1"  value="Reset Form">
  </fieldset>       
  </fieldset>
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: There's quite a few issues, firstly the closing `</form>` tag is outside the body, and secondly, the `Language` attribute was deprecated a few decades ago. Finally, here's the best lesson you'll learn all day...; Learn to properly indent code, and use the console. Go to this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/892to63j/), open the browser console (F12), and you can see the errors for yourself.

Comment: I have properly formatted your code. You should be able to see your errors just by looking at it now. Always keep your code formatted well so that you can see obvious errors (like the out-of-place and missing tags you have).

Comment: Why can't you get it to work? Do you get any errors, stacktraces, etc.?

Comment: Maybe it's my understanding of how everything works. It's my first time programming in html / javascript. I am currently learning html, javascript, c, c++ . So as you can imagine I am a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit mess, can I suggest to use jquery(https://jquery.com/download/)? It will make your life a lot of easier!

here is the jquery code that you need:

```
var confirmmsg = "";
var errflag = false; 
var errmsg = "";

$.each($('form input[type=radio]'), function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      confirmmsg += "<br> Overall is " + $(this).text();
    } else {
      errflag = true;
    }  
});

if (errflag) {
  errmsg  = "<br> You forgot to select an option";
}
```

This code takes each input radio element and check if it's checked and then make the confirmmsg and also if one of them it's not checked then the  errflag becomes true and also you set up the errmsg

btw, I think you need checkbox instead of radio inputs here

Answer (score 0):

(non jquery approach)

Form inputs that are "button" are simply buttons. You can attach event to those inputs, but they aren't related to submitting form. If you want to make button which will send form you should set "type" attribute to "submit". And then you can verify your form in JavaScript by adding event "onsubmit" to `<form>` tag, not the button. You can also use "onreset" to catch event if someone press button which cleans form. If you are adding "onsubmit" function, like:

```
onsumit="return testpage(this);"
```

you can easy decide inside that function, if form should be send or not. You can do this by returning value. If you return true, form will be send, and if you return false form will not be send. You can also disable sending form by setting "action" attribute of `<form>` tag to "javascript:void(0);"

In your code i would add "onsubmit" event to `<form>` tag and i would remove "onclick" from submit button (you are calling function and then posting form) and i also would change function code to:

```
function testpage(frm)
{
  var radioBoxSelected = false;
  for(var i=0; i < frm.elements.length;i++)
  {
    if (frm.elements[i].type == 'radio' && frm.elements[i].checked) {
      radioBoxSelected = true;
      val = frm.elements[i].value;
      // You can move messages to attribute "value" of radio boxes
      alert('You have selected: ' + val);
      // Below line sets some tag inner content to radiobox "value" attribute
      document.getElementById("satisfied_value").innerHTML = val;
      // Uncomment if you want send form here
      //return true;
    }
  }
  if (!radioBoxSelected) {
    alert('Please select option!');
    return false;
  }
}
```