# How can I use one event handler for multiple radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

I want mutliple radio buttons (number unknown, because they get created dynamcially) to have the same onClick or onChange event, whichever fits the best. I found examples for jQuery but not pure Javascript. Should i just loop trought all radio buttons on the form?

They get created in php like so:

```
//DB Connection already established 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results = $dbConnection->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $result->fetch-assoc()){
  echo "<li><input type=radio name=all_users[] value='". $row['E-Mail'] . "'/>" . $row['Name'] . " " . $row['Lastname'] . "</li>";
 }
}
else
{
  echo "<p>No users found</p>";
}
```

**How can i do that loop? Or is there any more common way of doing that?**

If one of them get's clicked i want their value as a parameter for the event, in only one function.

**Or Should i just add `onclick=myfunction(this)` into the php file?**

Comment: What have you tried so far in JavaScript?

Comment: @AndrewL the method to write onclick=myfunction(this) into the php file. But i'm sure there is a more "elegant" way to do this.

Comment: @WebNewbie this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35541346/9386929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want multiple radio buttons (number unknown, because they get created dynamically) to have the same onClick or onChange event.
>
> If one of them get's clicked i want their value as a parameter for the event, in only one function.

Let's assume that your PHP has rendered the list items and you have a common function called `myFunction()` which you want to use to log it's parameter to your console:

```
function myFunction(val){
    console.log("The value is " + val);
};
```

Now if I understand you correctly, you want to run the above function whenever one of the rendered radio buttons are clicked and to pass the value of the `value` attribute of the radio button that was clicked as a parameter for the above function.

**Firstly,** you need to assigned all the rendered radio button in your list to a variable:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li input");
```

**Secondly,** since `x` is a collection of objects (here, all the radio buttons rendered), you will now have to map through each item on x using `forEach` and assign a click listener on each radio button which runs the `ClickItem()`function passing it the item's `defaultValue` as a parameter `val` like this:

```
x.forEach(function(radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var val = this.defaultValue;
        myFunction(val);
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2y6eqhb0/56/

---

**However**, if by `value`, you mean the content after the `input` tag but still inside the respective `li` tag, then you just need to make slight changes to the above code like this:

**Firstly,** to prevent the selector from querying `li` elements from other parts of the page, you need to wrapped your list items with a div or a ul having a unique ID like this:

```
<ul id="someList">
    //create your list items here
</ul>
```

**Secondly,** you need to assigned all the rendered list items to a variable:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#someList li");
```

**Thirdly,** similarly to what we did above, since `x` is a collection of objects (here, all the list items rendered), you will now have to map through each item on x using `forEach` and assign a click listener on each list item which runs the `ClickItem()`function passing it the item's `innerText` as a parameter `val` like this:

```
x.forEach(function(radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var val = this.innerText;
        myFunction(val);
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2y6eqhb0/58/

Comment: Thanks for your time, will try that!

Comment: You're welcome mate. If one of the answers helped you, do mark it as the right answer to help future users having the same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the JQuery make it easier, but you can do the same with pure JS.
the real concept is to capture the event bubbling, try this:

fatherElement => element that is not dynamic

```
fatherElement.addEventListener("click", function(event){ 
    if(event.target.type == 'radio'){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `echo` line instead yours:

```
echo "<li><input onchange='yourOnChange(event)' type=radio name=all_users[] value='". $row['E-Mail'] . "'/>" . $row['Name'] . " " . $row['Lastname'] . "</li>";
```

I add `onchange='yourOnChange(event)'` there. And of course remember to add proper js function e.g `function yourOnChange(e) { console.log(e); }` to your web page.

Answer (score 0):

**Or Should i just add onclick=myfunction(this) into the php file?**

Yes, you can do that. In that case code will be;

```
<li><input onclick='myclick('". $row['E-Mail'] ."')' type=radio name=all_users[] value='". $row['E-Mail'] . "'/>" . $row['Name'] . " " . $row['Lastname'] . "</li>"
```

Now in JS code `myclick(email)` function can handle anything with email argument.

**Pure JS solution:**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'radio') {
        if(inputs[i].checked)
        {
             //if radio button is checked
             myClick(inputs[i].id, 'checked')  //you can get anything apart from id also
        }
        else
        {
             //if radio button is not checked
             myClick(inputs[i].id, 'unchecked')    //you can get anything apart from id also
        }
    }
}

myClick(id, stat)
{
    //YAY!! I have got the id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `for of` loop if you have `querySelectorAll`.

Here is an example:

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
for (const element of radios ) {element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget)
})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using pure JS you can select your radio buttons and add event listeners like so:

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

radios.forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('change', e => {
   // radio is your radio button element
});
```

Same with jQuery:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(() => {
   //your code goes here
});
```

Comment: You cannot do foreach on querySelectorAll, also you are missing a parenthesis in JS version